# How do I reconfigure Abe to work with Litecoin?

Tags: litecoin, abe

I succesfully launced [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/poliver/bitcoin-abe/) image. But I need one more instance as Litecoin blockchain explorer. How to configure it properly? Docker is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this configuration to work with Litecoin

```
{
  "chain": "Litecoin",
  "code3": "LTC",
  "address_version": "\x00",
  "magic": "\xfb\xc0\xb6\xdb",
  "policy": "Sha256Chain"
}
```

Its now hitting block **1201593** without any crashes. But still observing.